# Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name is too long

Tags: mysql

I receive a MySQL error when I create a table:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'FK_SALES_FLAT_CREDITMEMO_GRID_ARCHIVE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID' is too long
```

How can the default Identifier name size be increased or how can I solve this otherwise?

Comment: add your query here..........

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  You have to include relevant information, which in your case is the `create table` statement.

Comment: That is a good comment, however, this is enough information to start the investigation - if you have any identifiers over 64 chars.

Comment: Look for the supportive datatypes that can handle your data

Comment: @vinoth kumar: The error message says everything.

Comment: May this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170268/laravel-5-migration-identifier-name-too-long

Answer (score 43):

Please take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html - you are limited to 64 chars to an identifier.

Comment: Hi, please see the mysql error message below                                                               SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name                                                                'FK_SALES_FLAT_CREDITMEMO_GRID_ARCHIVE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID' is too long                                                                    How to solve the problem

Comment: How to increase it to more than 64 chars?

Comment: you cannot, you have to rename the foreign key

Answer (score 19):

Provide your own short name to key.

```
$table->unique(['product_id', 'company_id', 'price', 'delivery_hours'], 'prices_history_index_unique');
```

Comment: For context, this answer explains how you can fix this issue with **Laravel**, when it automatically creates unique keys that are too long. In your migration you can ad the line above

Answer (score 0):

Just give the primary key a shorter name.

Like this:

```
$table->primary(['company_store_id', 'company_product_id'], 'product_store_id');
```